# image slider in android need it to be scrollable up and down

Tags: android

I want to add a image slider in my application using
 (https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) but I want it to be scrollable . I mean I am having a recycler view below this slider and I want when user scroll the list to see the list items image slider should also scroll up and down as user wants ..  i have pasted my xml below please tell me what should I do.

this is the image url to see the screen shot of the app.
http://picpaste.com/U-04sZEbuG.png

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

       <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
          layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

           <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#ffffff">
              <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/TextLinear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/navbarblue"
                android:gravity="center">
           <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
               android:text="VIEW BOOKS BY YOUR BRANCH"
               android:id="@+id/textView"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
               android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

             <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextLinear" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_below="@id/slider"
                android:id="@+id/MainList"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
         </RelativeLayout>

           <fragment
             android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
              android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_gravity="start"
                   app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
               android:name="com.example.sky.learn.NavigationDrawerFragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

                </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>




          </LinearLayout>
```